# How to handle user defined exception in Firebird procedure?

Tags: exception, firebird, firebird2.5

I created exception:

`CREATE EXCEPTION E_NO_CLIENT 'Client was not found.' ;`

Then call it in procedure

`if (inv_port is null) then EXCEPTION e_no_client;`

And before the last `end` of procedure i am trying to handle exception:

```
       when SQLCODE 219 /*e_no_client*/ do
            begin
             error_code = 1;
             execute procedure p_LOG('p_DEAL: Client was not find.');
             -- select * from RDB$EXCEPTIONS;
             EXCEPTION;
            end
```

The question is what i need to write after `when` to execute statement after `do`?

I tried to write `when E_NO_CLIENT` and  `RDB$EXCEPTION_NUMBER` from `RDB$EXCEPTIONS` table (as in example code).

Comment: If you tag with _firebird2.5_, then also tag with _firebird_

Answer (score 2):

'exception' after 'when' helps me:

```
   when exception e_no_client  do
        begin
         error_code = 1;
         execute procedure p_LOG('p_DEAL: Client was not find.');
         suspend;
        end
```

Comment: See also [Trapping and Handling Errors](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql-handleexceptions.html) in the Firebird 2.5 language reference